# PowerShell automate build issue with RestorePackages

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have implemented a automation build from the following

http://geekswithblogs.net/dwdii/archive/2011/05/27/part-2-automating-a-visual-studio-build-with-powershell.aspx

I am facing a problem like some of the Nuget packages are not getting restored. So is there any possibility to restore the packages from PowerShell script?

**Note : If I open up the solution in visual studio and restoring the packages automation is working fine**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [nuget command line documentation on Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#command-line-restore), for NuGet 4.0+ and MSBuild 15.1+, you can use:

```
MSBuild /t:restore
```

I believe you would need to pass the solution or project file also to the above command, such as:

```
MSBuild /t:restore app.sln
```

Or for Nuget 2.7 and above:

```
nuget.exe restore app.sln
```

Both of these approaches would be callable from Powershell and a simple batch file.

See also: [Nuget MSBuild Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets)